# Trying to Use System.Diagnostics.Process v4.3 Encounters a v4.1 Not Found Error

Tags: nuget-package, system.diagnostics

I have the "System.Diagnostics.Process" v4.3 NuGet installed but when trying to use one of its functions I encounter a "can't find v4.1" error.

I needed the Nuget. I initially installed v4.1 because I am working on software supporting older OS's, but it was not compatible so I install v4.3 which was compatible with my solution.

I have searched for code/files referencing the library, but none seem to specify it other than the csproject which references the v4.3 version. I have reinstalled the NuGet. I have clean the solution and deleted the bin/obj directories. I have clean the NuGet caches and force a reload. The v4.3 DLL is present in a number of paths/folders, but not v4.1 DLL.

Is there somewhere else that I should look for the specification/path of the lib being used?

Error:

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Sentry.CognitiveServices.GetPathWithGetMappedFileName(SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle memoryMappedViewHandle)
   at Sentry.CognitiveServices.<SpeakNarrative>d__13.MoveNext()}
```

Expect V4.3 to be referenced, not v4.1.

Comment: What is your target framework?

Comment: Cross-platform Xamarin UWP at this moment.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with Xamarin and UWP but the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814993.aspx) says UWP supports .NET Standard 2.0.  So you could try get rid of NuGet and reference it directly from framework.  If you were on .NET I would suggest to move to .NET 4.7.2 and update MSBuild to latest version.

If you are sure that your code references 4.3 then it is some dependency which needs 4.1.  Have you tried bindingRedirect 0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0 -> 4.3.0.0?

Comment: Just as unfortunately, I can't move to .NET 4.7.2 and maintain the compatibility to devices I need.

Comment: kiril is right, [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Diagnostics.Process) is supported by .net stadnard 2.0. so set MinVersion of the UWP to at least Build 16299 and in .net standard 2.0 lib which you use as shared code just use it without installing anything.

Comment: The reason that System.DIagnostics.Process 4.3 is supported by .NETStandard 2.0 is that it only requires .NETStandard 1.4 which is install. The NuGet was the last added to the so there should be no dependencies other than those it had added with itself. That shouldn't create the backwards reference I am experiencing.

Comment: Marc, have you tried binding redirect?  It usually solves such conflicts.

Comment: UWP in Xamarin Forms no longer uses a "app.config" file. Do you know how to do a binding redirect that would work for all the OS's? The NuGet is attached to the PCL.

Comment: again, stop adding nuget and simply call the functions you want after converting PCL to .net standard 2.0